# sapui5 - Object doesn't support property or method 'getTime'

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to format the date in sapui5. I have tried a couple of stackoverflow suggestion but no success. Date format I get back from oracle db is `2017-10-12T00:00:00.000Z`. Please guide. This is my code

```
<Column>
    <m:Label text="Last Load Date" tooltip="Last Load Date"/>
    <template>
       <m:Label text="${ path: 'LAST_UPDATE', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { pattern: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}"/>
    </template>
</Column>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because "sap.ui.model.type.Date" expects the data in the following format (ABAP backned uses it):

/Date(TIMESTAMP)/

So 2 solutions:

1. Adjust you backend to return the required date property structure;
2. Implement your custom data type (based on a standard one), which will work with the format as you described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.What I did was use custom formatter instead of sapui5 date formatter.

```
new sap.m.Text({
    text: {
        path: "LAST_UPDATE",
        formatter: function(dateF) {
            var date = new Date(dateF);
            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
            var dd = date.getDate();
            var fhh = date.getHours();
            var fmm = date.getMinutes();
            var fss = date.getSeconds();
            var dateFormated = date.getFullYear() + "/" +
                (mm > 9 ? '' : '0') + mm + "/" +
                (dd > 9 ? '' : '0') + dd + " " +
                (fhh > 9 ? '' : '0') + fhh + ":" +
                (fmm > 9 ? '' : '0') + fmm +
                ":" + (fss > 9 ? '' : '0') + fss;
            return "Last updated : " + dateFormated;
        }
    },
})
```